# Calculating the charge of an $sp_z$ hybridized orbital using charge density $\rho$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, atomic-physics, orbitals

I have a homework problem that is asking to verify that the total charge for an electron is -1.  The electron is in an $sp_z$ hybridized orbital with the shape:

[image: Picture of the orbital]

We are given the charge density as:$$\rho(r,\theta,\phi)=-\frac 1 {64\pi}e^{-r}(r-2-r\cos\theta)^2.$$

I understand the simple equation to find the total charge is $Q=\rho V$ where $V$ is the volume of a sphere, but here, we don't have a sphere.  I am wondering how to parameterize this shape and if I can set up an integral such as
$$\int_{0}^{R}dr\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi$$ to integrate the charge density to find the total charge.  Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the simple equation to find the total charge is $Q=\rho V$ where $V$ is the volume of a sphere,

The simple equation $$Q=\rho V$$
is applicable only if the charge density is
homogenous, i.e. independent of position in space.
But in your case the charge density $\rho(r,\theta,\phi)$
does depend on the position in space ($r,\theta,\phi$).
Therefore you can only use differential relation
$$dQ=\rho\ dV$$
which is valid for infinitesimal small volume elements $dV$.

> I am wondering how to parameterize this shape and if I can set up an integral such as
> $$\int_{0}^{R}dr\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi$$

Yes, that is roughly the way to go.

But you got the ranges of the spherical coordinates $r$ and $\theta$ wrong.
Look at the geometrical definition of spherical coordinates to get the correct ranges.

You also need to express the volumen element $dV$ in terms of $r$, $\theta$, $\phi$.
Hint: It is not simply $dV=dr\ d\theta\ d\phi$.
I'm sure you will find the correct expression in your textbook or course notes.

Then you can finally calculate the integral
$$Q=\int dQ=\int \rho\ dV=...$$